# How to jump a cycle If?

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a Windows Form Application, which has a `TextBox` where you can enter a number that is modified by my program.

I created an `if` clause and if the `TextBox.Text` is empty, I do not want to run the calculations. But even if I leave the `TextBox` empty, an exception rises because there is no value. How can I skip this `if` clause?

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string strMP3Folder = @"C:\Users\Stefano\Music\shake.mp3";

            string strMP3OutputFilename = @"C:\Users\Stefano\Music\funziona2.mp3";

            using (Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader(strMP3Folder))
            {
                int count = 1;
                Mp3Frame mp3Frame = reader.ReadNextFrame();
                System.IO.FileStream _fs = new System.IO.FileStream(strMP3OutputFilename, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);

                double valoreIniziale = 0;
                if (textBox2.Text != null)
                {
                    valoreIniziale = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
                }

                double valorefinale = 1000000;
                if (textBox1.Text != null)
                { valorefinale = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you retrieve the `TextBox.Text` property, the "getter" runs the following code:

```
return (text == null) ? "" : text;
```

The `Text` property *never* returns `null`, and so your code as you currently have it will *always* execute.

Instead, just test for the empty string:

```
if (textBox2.Text != "")
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First thing "if" is not loop. Secondly If I understood correctly you want to neglect "if" block in case your text inside text box is empty or null. If that is what you want you can do it by :

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
```